# Docker-compose crashes after running for hours with

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a springBoot app running in an docker container on a ec2 instance. I ran fine for many month but since a few days( I only change small thing in the application). Docker crashes and when I try to restart with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I checked the permissions there all fine. I don't need sudo.

If course I can just start docker service again. And then run docker-compose. .. but after a few hours it happens again. 
Anybody any idea or how to debug ist.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx-xxx6 docker]$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 8
Server Version: 18.09.9-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.171-136.231.amzn2.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 983.4MiB
Name: ip-xxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal
ID: BCL7:57U4:NUOW:UEW3:XQDK:TWMA:QKWL:GCMA:IFVH:JHCU:XE6S:JGZN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your docker daemon in the background stopped working. 
This might be related to your app, or the installation.

For the second you could try to setup a new / different ec2 host and see if it happens again.

For the first I would check the docker containers you are running, to see of you need to change some configuration on the host to have it running in a stable way.